# Firebaserecyclerview Gravity

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to create a Chat App. It is working really good. But now I'd like to gravity the messages. I don't know how I can set the gravity of the sent messages to the right side. `viewHolder.mView.setForegroundGravity();` doesn't work.

```
public void populateViewHolder(final BlogViewHolder viewHolder, final Blog model, final int position) {
    DatabaseReference getname = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userID).child("Username");
    getname.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //Grün und weiß setzen
            String myname = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            if(myname.equals(model.getUsername())){
                LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.singleMessageContainer);
                linear.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                viewHolder.setNachricht(model.getNachricht());
            }else{
                viewHolder.setNachricht(model.getNachricht());
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}
```

---

```
public static class BlogViewHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    View mView;
    public BlogViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
    }
    public void setNachricht(String Nachricht){
        TextView post_Nachricht = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.textViewMessage);
        post_Nachricht.setText(Nachricht);
    }
    public void setUsername(String Username){
        TextView post_Nachricht = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.kommentareimg);
        post_Nachricht.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + Username + ":</b>"));
    }
}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/singleMessageContainer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="6dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/warpper"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewMessage"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:text="Message"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: So... Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

In your case you might consider having two `TextView` in your list item layout. Make the layout such that one layout is aligned to the right and the other is aligned to the left. Now you just have to set the visibility of the left or right layout to `GONE` or `VISIBLE`.

So you need to have some other functions in your `ViewHolder` class.

```
public static class BlogViewHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    View mView;
    public BlogViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
    }

    public void setNachrichtRight(String Nachricht) {
        TextView post_Nachricht_Right = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.textViewMessageRight);
        TextView post_Nachricht_Left = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.textViewMessageLeft);
        post_NachrichtRight.setText(Nachricht);

        // Now set the visibility
        post_Nachricht_Right.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        post_Nachricht_Left.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    public void setNachrichtLeft(String Nachricht) {
        TextView post_NachrichtLeft = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.textViewMessageLeft);
        TextView post_NachrichtRight = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.textViewMessageRight);
        post_NachrichtLeft.setText(Nachricht);

        // Now set the visibility
        post_Nachricht_Right.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        post_Nachricht_Left.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    public void setUsername(String Username){
        TextView post_Nachricht = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.kommentareimg);
        post_Nachricht.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + Username + ":</b>"));
    }
}
```

So inside the `onDataChange` function you may consider doing something like this.

```
if(myname.equals(model.getUsername())){
    viewHolder.setNachrichtRight(model.getNachricht());
} else {
    viewHolder.setNachrichtLeft(model.getNachricht());
}
```

Finally, your layout may look something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/singleMessageContainer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="6dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewMessageRight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:text="Message"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewMessageLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:text="Message"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

</RelativeLayout>
```